# Selenium ,window_handles не выдает только один id окна хотя я зашел уже на вторую вкладку

Tags: python, selenium

```
driver.get(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIJ5Glk4geM&list=PLqGS6O1-DZLp1kgiQNpueIMCHRNzgHa1r&index=9)

elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'style-scope ytd-watch-next-secondary-results-renderer').click()
```

print(driver.window_handles)# выводит только один id хотя заходил я в две вкладки.

Как это исправить?

Заранее спасибо !!!

Answer (score 0):

Сам джун и не уверен, но насколько я знаю - при клике не всегда открывется новое окно. Для этого используется другой метод. Поэтому и окно открыто всего одно
(сам сталкивался, что на одном и том же сайте при клике на один элемент просто переходит к  элементу, а на другой - открывает новое окно - это сделано изначально разработчиками сайта. Но если вы специально не открываете новое окно - оно скорее всего как новое и не откроется)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: спасибо  большое